# Beginner Problems with Equals Operator

Tags: powershell

everyone trying to learn Powershell off and on and I'm stuck on this problem. I cannot seem to find an equals operator that this code will accept at  the **= true portion .** 
Ive tried -eq, =, ==, and === .
Trying to get the Msg box to pop up if this Test-path command returns a true condition.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

If( Test-Path 'C:\wmw\~$test.xlsx' **= True)**
{
     $wshell.Popup("Hey $Env:ComputerName This file is in use!",0,"test")}
else

{$wshell.Popup("Hey $Env:ComputerName This file is not in use!",0,"test")}
```

Comment: It's just `If(Test-Path 'C:\wmw\~$test.xlsx')`. You don't need equals after it; if it's true, the if succeeds, and if it's false the if fails.

Comment: Duh lol Thanks was having a brain fart. Sometimes the issue is more simple than you realize. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the literal for `true` is `$true` in PowerShell. And the operator for equality comparison is `-eq`. Then there is the issue that parameters to cmdlets start with `-` and you'd need to wrap the command in parentheses. Otherwise `-eq` would be interpreted as a (non-existent) parameter to `Test-Path`. So putting that all together:

```
If( (Test-Path 'C:\wmw\~$test.xlsx') -eq $True) { ... }
```

or, since `if` just needs a value that can be coerced to a boolean you don't even need the explicit comparison in most cases:

```
if (Test-Path 'C:\wmw\~$test.xlsx') { ... }
```

---

One hint for future exploration of the shell: Read the error messages. Most of the time they are helpful.

Omitting the parentheses and using `-eq` tells you about the fact that it's interpreted as a parameter:

> Test-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'eq'.

Same with `=` which is interpreted as a parameter *value* here:

> Test-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='.

Using parentheses correctly and using `-eq` breaks the parser, admittedly:

> You must provide a value expression following the '-eq' operator.
>   Unexpected token 'True' in expression or statement.
>   Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
>   Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.

Using parentheses and `=` is helpful again:

> The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.